# Index of Laravel Project Showing

Tags: php, laravel, indexing, visible

So I've installed Laravel (5.2) on an Ubuntu server and it seems to be working fine with one issue however; when I go to the page/URL it shows the index of the project.

I know this question has been asked many times, and I've looked at the posts, but nothing seems to be helping so I was wondering if anyone has any other suggestions/fixes that could solve my issue.

If you'd like to see my config for apache, I'll link it.

Comment: Please provide more information about your specific situation.

Comment: http://myles.i.pxl.lt/JoKwHm this is what happens when I go to the URL that it's setup on; and if I add /public to it, it'll redirect to the normal Laravel placeholder page.

Comment: You have to point the apache conf you have setup for the site with the fully qualified path including /public .( ie: /var/www/html/your_site_folder/publc) set as the DocumentRoot and in the Directory node. You should also set up your 000-Default.conf to not show indexes...very bad on a public facing server unless your serving up a file directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!